# サブクラスを想定に入れたinstancetypeを返すクラスメソッドをSwiftで書き換える方法は？

Tags: objective-c, swift

```
@interface AClass : NSObject
+ (instancetype)hoge;
@end

@interface BClass : AClass
@end

@implementation AClass
+ (instancetype)hoge {
    return [self new];
}
@end

@implementation BClass
@end


id objA = [A hoge];    // AClass's instance
id objB = [B hoge];    // BClass's instance
```

このクラスをSwiftで書き換えることは出来ますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class AClass : NSObject {
    required override init() {}

    class func hoge() -> Self {
        return self()
    }
}

class BClass : AClass {
}

var objA = AClass.hoge();
var objB = BClass.hoge();
```